# Make multiple uiview like cardex view

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm new in iOS.
I have a big problem, I must create app in iPad
I must show multiple UIView and create Card Animation like in Roambi Cardex View

this video describe a cardex view :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CL1uIS-xoPU

Anyone can help me ?
Pleaseee....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread, but for for future reference, [iCarousel](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel) might be the thing that you want. Again, you would have to customize it to your liking, but it's a great piece of code!